# Why is this morphism a homeomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Why is the morphism of affine varieties $$ \varphi :  \mathbb{A}^1 \to \mathcal{V}(X^3-Y^2) \subset \mathbb{A}^2, \quad r \mapsto (r^2,r^3),\;$$
a homeomorphism? It is obviously bijective, so it remains to show that the image of an arbritary variety $V \subset \mathbb{A}^1$ under $\varphi$ is a subvariety of $\mathcal{V}(X^3-Y^2)$.

Comment: You have to check inverse images as well.

Comment: True! I am making use of the fact that morphisms are continuous...

Comment: That's a good idea. Indeed, polynomial functions are continuous w.r.t. the Zariski topology.

Comment: Did you already classify the (irreducible) varieties of $\mathbb{A}^1$?

Comment: No, but I'll think about how that could help...

Comment: The irreducible varieties in $\mathbb{A}^1$ (over an algebraically closed field) are simple. Maybe it can help. But I think there should be an easier way.

Comment: I have an idea (thanks to your hint): Since $V \subset \mathbb{A}^1$ is finite, say $V = \{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$, we have $\varphi(V) = \{(a_i^2,a_i^3); i =1,\dots n\} = \mathcal{V} (X - a_1^2, \dots, X - a_n^2) \subset \mathcal{V}(X^3-Y^2)$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Non trivial varieties must be finite because a polynomial in one variable has only finitely many roots.